# Is it possible to mount a blank writable dvd iso image?

Tags: windows, iso-image

I would like to make some old programs that I have burn directly to a iso file.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

THere are at least two programs that will let you do this:

Phantom Burner: http://www.phantombility.com/en/prod/phantomburner/

Phantom Drive: http://www.phantom-drive.com/en/default.htm

Neither of them are free of charge though although they both have trial versions.

Comment: I'd add totalmounter to that list.

Answer (score -1):

i doubt it would be possible to make a mountable and writable blank CD/DVD image. however, there are applications that can create ISO files, which could then be used to burn a CD/DVD. quick [search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=create+ISO+file&form=OSDSRC&adlt=strict) on Bing.

Comment: I can confirm CD (iso 9660) is not possible. Not sure about UDF support for writing.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it is possible to mount a blank writable `.iso` DVD image.

But you can make an `.iso` file containing all the programs you want using a disk image utility like [PowerISO](http://www.poweriso.com/)

> PowerISO is a disk image utility that can open, burn, create, edit,
>   compress, encrypt, mount and extract ISO files.

These features of PowerISO might interest you

> - Create ISO file or BIN file from hard disk files or CD / DVD / BD
>     discs.
> - Edit ISO image file directly.

Although note that

> Free unregistered versions will allow you to evaluate the software for
>   free to determine if it suits your needs. The unregistered version
>   will display a dialog prompts you to register, and you can not create
>   or edit image files greater than **300MB** with the unregistered version.

So if your *some old programs* are less than 300MB you can use this utility.

---

As mentioned in @Xantec answer you can also search for some other disk image utilities.